# Cannot access Docker container remotely

Tags: docker, debian, docker-network

So I have a custom Docker image based on Debian (essentially just installs some extra packages and copies a few files to configure the web server). However, I have been unable to get access to the web server externally.

The command I use to run the image after being built is:

```
docker container run --publish 8080:80 --name ipcast -t -d ipcast
```

Of course, the first thing I assumed was that the port was not open in the Firewall, though I double checked the Firewall and it seems to be open through all hops to the Docker host.

Furthermore, I ran `nmap -p 8080 ourdockerserver.com` on my remote machine and it yielded:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

Which implies that the port is open in the Firewall (since it's `closed` not `filtered`) just that nothing is listening on it.

Nevertheless, when I run `netstat -tulpn` on the Docker host, I can see it running on port 8080:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      579620/docker-proxy
```

And running `nmap -p 8080 localhost` on the Docker host seems to work fine:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

I'm not particularly knowledgeable with IP Tables, however, I've never seen a port being used internally but closed externally without being filtered by a Firewall. I understand that this may be something to do with the port forwarding magic that Docker does on the host but I cannot get it to work even after scouring the internet.

I also tried creating a bridged network with `docker network create -d bridge my-net` and then running my container with:

```
docker container run --network my-net --publish 8080:80 --name ipcast -t -d ipcast
```

This did not work either...

Comment: I hope you are using port 8080 (and not 80) while accessing the application. Also, run `docker ps ` command to verify that the container is running. Many a time (especially when we build a custom Docker image) it happens that the container exists due to inappropriate CMD. Check container logs if the container has exited using `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME` command.

Comment: As I understand your config: You have a Container running on Host A and want to access that container from Host B (external). But you need  software listening on Host A and passing requests on to the Container? A ProxyServer.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal as mentioned, I'm running nmap using port 8080 so yes I am trying to connect to port 8080 and not port 80 on my remote machine. I can also verify that the container is running as expected.

Comment: @BertC yes you are correct, I was under the assumption that Docker adds these port forwarding rules automatically.